# Serve static files via a subdomain on a wordpress

Tags: apache, nginx, hosting

I want to serve the wp-content/uploads directory using a subdomain.

I launched a wordpress instance on aws lightsail(with bitnami)

I want a configuration on how to do that.

Something similar to the config below(using nginx)

```
server {
  root /var/www/images.domain.com/wp-content/uploads;
  server_name images.domain.com;
  listen 80;

  location ~* ^.+\.(png|jpe?g|json|js|txt|ico)$ {      
    add_header Cache-Control 'public, max-age=259200000';      
    root /var/www/images.domain.com/wp-content/uploads;}
  }
```